# Error Executing javascript (Ajax) using HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, htmlunit

I,m using HtmlUnit version 2.43.
When I click the button and call Ajax JavaScript the Re-synchronized call to https://www.licitacoes-e.com.br/aop/listar-lotes.aop?opcao=listarLotesPosCaptcha&numeroLicitacao=824678&numeroLoteInicial=0&numeroLoteFinal=0&question=68pwr it's ok, this link is correct, but the original Page doesn't change always stay like before.

My Code:

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

    CookieManager cookieManager = client.getCookieManager();
    cookieManager.setCookiesEnabled(true);
    client.setCookieManager(cookieManager);
    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    client.getOptions().setPopupBlockerEnabled(true);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    client.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    client.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    .....
    HtmlTextInput inputCaptcha = 
      paginaAfterConsultaIdentificadorCaptcha.querySelector("input[name='questionCL']");
    inputCaptcha.setValueAttribute("68pwr");

    paginaAfterConsultaIdentificadorCaptcha = ((HtmlButtonInput) 
    paginaAfterConsultaIdentificadorCaptcha.getElementById("botao_continuar")).click();
    client.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
    System.out.println(paginaAfterConsultaIdentificadorCaptcha.asXml());

     I already tried this too:
      for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            synchronized (paginaAfterConsultaIdentificadorCaptcha) {
                paginaAfterConsultaIdentificadorCaptcha.wait(10000);
            }
        }
       System.out.println(paginaAfterConsultaIdentificadorCaptcha.asXml());
```

But paginaAfterConsultaIdentificadorCaptcha doesn't change.

In console log show me:

```
2020-09-14 15:39:45.201  INFO 2573 --- [pool-2-thread-1] .g.h.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController : Re-synchronized call to https://www.licitacoes-e.com.br/aop/listar-lotes.aop?opcao=listarLotesPosCaptcha&numeroLicitacao=824678&numeroLoteInicial=0&numeroLoteFinal=0&question=68pwr

2020-09-14 15:39:47.687  WARN 2573 --- [Client@2760b96d] c.g.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript             : Script is not JavaScript (type: 'true/text/javascript', language: ''). Skipping execution.

2020-09-14 15:39:47.687  WARN 2573 --- [Client@2760b96d] c.g.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript             : 
Script is not JavaScript (type: 'true/text/javascript', language: ''). Skipping execution.
```

Please, someone can help me?

Comment: I realized that deleting the cookies (JSESSIONID) in Browser(FireFox) show the same page that the htmlunit after execute Ajax. But I put the cookie in code and the page doesn't return expected page.

Comment: I realized too that the new page that is call by ajax has a code  
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  inicializaScripts();
 });
</script>

but not refer um jquery file. 
Will be that it can be the error?

Comment: I believe that the error is when the ajax call open the link. This page needs the cookies, but I don't know. I tried everything. I putted the cookies in webClient, putted in header but doen't work. Really, I need help.